# is there a way to reload the iframe body content, and skip scripts reloading?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have a page, which contains an iframe and a menu which navigates between pages that located on my server, and should be loaded into the iframe. 
All the pages share big javascript files, and I want to know if there's a way to reload only the content of the inner page, without reloading the scripts, or if there's a way to load the scripts on the "master" page, and use them in the inner pages.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you concern about size and afraid of repeated downloads of same files - the best way is to let the browser cache this files. Actually, if you doing things right - the js files already must be cached and not downloaded again on iframe reload. (Also, you can use AppCache for modern browsers).

The caching can be a tricky thing, but you can check HTTP headers what is returned on requiest  of this files and tune them for you needs.
 **Cache-control**, **max-age** and **expires** your first friends.